# How to create a custom paragraph block that preprocesses multiple Javascript Files?

Tags: 8, blocks, hooks

I am trying to create a custom block that preprocesses inputted JS files in a node to load in the header of specific pages that have that block reference in a paragraph.

```
if ($vars['elements']['#id'] == 'myblock') {
    $vars['#attached']['library'][] = $vars['content'][''];
  }
```

What do I need to add to this to make it so it will read what is in the block and load that js if the block is referenced in a node?

I am a bit lost so any help would be great!

Comment: This is going to be complicated. What is a Paragraph Block? Is it a Paragraph? Or a custom block type? If it is just a Paragraph, you can preprocess the Paragraph and attach the library which will add the library any time that Paragraph is rendered.

Comment: It is a paragraph that is just a block reference of a custom block type.

Comment: @Kevin I meant to say its a custom block that needs to be referenced in a paragraph.